# Can't get blog entry to format properly using wp-load

Tags: formatting

I'm setting up a blog that I'm trying to integrate the posts of into old site pages. The

```
$id = $_GET['article_id'];
$post = get_post($id);
setup_postdata($post);
echo $post->post_content;
```

However, when I echo the blog post from `$post->post_content`, it seems that the html has been stripped out. The lines all run together. There are line breaks in the source, but there are no html `<BR>`s or `<p>`s. However, the post looks fine when I view it through the actual WordPress page.

I have to use `<pre>` to get it to display properly, but then on the page, lines don't wrap and it defaults to that typewriter font.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post content, stored in database, is not equal to what gets displayed. It should be displayed with template tag function or at least run through `the_content` filter. Try:

```
the_content();
```

Or:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
```